# How to get content of "secured" dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

The question to all Python Masters. I have `box` variable, defined that way:

```py
class BlackBox(dict): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlackBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def keys(self):     return None
    def pop(self):      return None
    def __iter__(self): return None

    def items(self):     return None
    def popitem(self):   return None
    def values(self):    return None
    def __repr__(self):  return None
    def __str__(self):   return None

box = BlackBox({'some_secret_key' : 'I am secure content'})
```

How can I get the content of `box` without knowing the secret key?

Thank you.

**UPD:** python 3.7.4 and higher

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to raise an error instead of returning `None`?

Comment: Why inherit from `dict` at all? Also note Python doesn't tolerate hiding much. Its philosophy differs from other languages and mindsets

Comment: Even if you could find a way to restrict access to the data in the class objects, you can still read process memory with other applications.

Comment: If I were looking at implementing an object that served as a container for secure information, I'd do some research into TPM API's (trusted platform module). I believe that it can securely hold secret keys and provides some sort of encryption/decryption services to applications.. Your secret dict could hold encrypted information that's only accessible to someone who knows the password.. or to the application that can somehow control what gets decrypted for the user.. otherwise the data could be read by another process but not decrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really must, then use the super-class method. Try:

```
print(dict.items(box))
```

Comment: You've found the gap... will try to provide the fix and update the question soon

Comment: @1844144 You may find there is more than one "gap" in your leaky bucket

Comment: `dict.keys(box)` also gets info.

Answer (score 1):

`box.copy()` will get the items

If `copy()` and other methods were supposed to be overridden as well, then look at @Luv's answer.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: @1844144 I just tried it and it works; `copy()` is not overridden

Comment: can not reproduce... what version of python you are using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5, are you using 2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212522/discussion-between-1844144-and-afghanimah).

Answer (score 1):

If you are hoping to produce a "secure" data structure in **python alone** then you will be ultimately disappointed.  Assuming you are in python 2.7 (by the way you called `super`), then here are some very easy ways to crack your current type.

```
>>> dict(box)
{'some_secret_key': 'I am secure content'}
>>> box.copy()
{'some_secret_key': 'I am secure content'}
>>> super(type(box), box).items()
[('some_secret_key', 'I am secure content')]
>>> def safe_cracker(**kw): return kw
>>> safe_cracker(**box)
{'some_secret_key': 'I am secure content'}
```

In python 3 there are less ways, but here are some ways it leaks

```
>>> box.get("some_secret_key")
'I am secure content'
>>> super(type(box), box).items()
dict_items([('some_secret_key', 'I am secure content')])
>>> box.setdefault("some_secret_key")
'I am secure content'
>>> "some_secret_key" in box
True
```

(As long as you inherit from `dict`, then anyone can use `dict` based methods to directly interrogate the structure, such as `dict.items(box)` or `super(type(box), box).items()`)

Comment: Please note you will not know secret key. ... but anyway you are right there is a Trouble in inheritance from type which I can not override

Comment: @1844144 Yes ... but I can test for random keys at the rate of 15-20m a second so it won't take too long to brute force it.

Comment: Key will be long enough and time limit is short enough to prevent brute force. 
Thank you for idea of using something *beyond* python.

As @Luv was first with idea of super-class methods, I will accept his answer.
Appreciate your help.